# what graphics library would i need to run java?

Tags: java, operating-system

i am looking into making my own OS just to say i've done it. i know that there is a project called JNode that has done one in assembly and java. 
 what i was wondering was, what embedded graphics do you need to run java? i know java uses the graphics of the specific os so this confuses me

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to port the JVM to your OS. Have a look at the [Java Virtual Machine spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html). It will tell you exactly what need to implement to support Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to implement AWT/Swing, then you obviously need to have some kind of library that can draw 2D graphics in a screen. I'd recommend however to start from implementing the virtual machine and some basic libraries. Printing in a screen will be sufficient.

Have a look [here](http://netwinder.osuosl.org/users/a/andrewt/public_html/java.html) for a list of implementations of JAVA for the ARM platform. [Kaffe](http://www.kaffe.org/) is interesting.

Comment: i'm looking to implement awt/swing could i use the same libraries most linux systems operate under? or could i use something like opengl as the systems library?

Comment: OpenGL doesn't have the line and curve primitives used in Graphic2D, but is used in Sun's Java implementation to improve some pixmap rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Java can run in headless mode.  That might be a good starting point suitable for server side stuff, which you can then extend if you feel like it.

Have a look at Sanos - http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/ - which is a tiny OS providing just the facilities needed to run the Windows JVM.